# How i can execute git clone command without executing "git init" command in my local folder?

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to clone a project from github to my local created folder. However, when i execute "git clone" command i have below error.

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I execute "git init" command on that folder and this error disappear, but in the following path I must "add" and "commit" the added and committed remote repository again. This is what I do not want.

Comment: After git clone you have to cd into the clone.

Answer (score 1):

The `git clone` command:

1. Makes a new folder.
2. **In the new folder**, runs `git init` and a whole series of additional Git commands.  The clone is now *in* the *new folder*.

**You, however, are *not* in the new folder.**  You are still in the same folder ("current working directory" is the more technical term for this) as you have been all along.  You must move your own command-line interpreter into the new folder too, before you make use of the new clone.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to git clone is to use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli).

Once [installed](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation=), authenticate yourself with [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login), then create your new repository with [`gh repo clone`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone), with a simplified URL "`OWNER/REPO`" instead of "`https://github.com/OWNER/REPO`":

```bash
# Cloning a repository
~/Projects$ gh repo clone cli/cli
Cloning into 'cli'...
~/Projects$ cd cli
~/Projects/cli$
```

Note that you still have to *`cd`* (change directory) into the cloned repository.